# MySQL procedure performance issue because of NAME_CONST

Tags: php, mysql, performance, cursor

I am executing the below procedure on two version of MySQL on the same data and I see significant different in performance.
When i run "show full processlist".
The only difference I see is that MySQL version 5.5.15 generates NAME_CONST and COLLATE for every SELECT like the below.
The character set on both the DBs are latin1.

DECLARE PROCEDURE Sample()
    BEGIN
    DECLARE A_Val int;
    DECLARE B_Val varchar(50);

```
DECLARE ApplCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT A, CONVERT(B, CHAR(50))
    FROM SampleTable;


OPEN ApplCursor;

Cursor_Loop: LOOP
    FETCH ApplCursor INTO A_Val, B_Val;

    SELECT B_Val, X_Val FROM SomeTableX;

END LOOP Cursor_Loop;

CLOSE ApplCursor;
```

END;

MySQL version = 5.5.15 
For every select MySQL generates a NAME_CONST and COLLATE, as seen below

select NAME_CONST('B_Val',_latin1'A12345' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci'), X_Val
from SomeTableX;

MySQL version = 5.7.16 
The same SQL is generated with out NAME_CONST and COLLATE and execues much much faster

select B_Val, X_Val  from SomeTableX;

Can someone suggest as to how to disable the NAME_CONST and COLLATE generation.
Is there a way to tell MySQL to stop generating these extra NAME_CONST and COLLATE???

Comment: A wild guess why one MySQL version might be faster than the other: there has been some technical improvement in the last 5 years. What should your code do anyway? Your current procedure does not make much sense, or is it just to have a test case? You might want to do the same test, but select 2 columns from your table instead of variables (e.g. `select x_val, x_val from sometablex`) and check if it is still slower.

Answer (score 2):

So `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE` on both servers.  You will probably see that they were built with different `CHARACTER SET` and/or `COLLATION`.

Comment: That is very useful info Rick. But is there a way to set the CHARACTER SET and COLLATION of a procedure?

Comment: Set them for your connection, `DROP` the SP, re-`CREATE` it, then check via `SHOW CREATE ...`

Answer (score 0):

### Try this:

```
 DECLARE ApplCursor CURSOR FOR
       SELECT A, CONVERT(B, CHAR(50)) FROM SampleTable;

 OPEN ApplCursor;
 Cursor_Loop: LOOP

     FETCH ApplCursor INTO A_Val, B_Val; 
     set ins_query=CONCAT(" SELECT ",B_Val,",",X_Val," FROM SomeTableX");
     set @ins_query=ins_query;
     PREPARE ins_query from @ins_query;
     EXECUTE ins_query;

END LOOP Cursor_Loop;
CLOSE ApplCursor;
```